# Alignment issue in the individual badge details page

Tags: bug, design, badges, display-names

There is an alignment issue in the individual badge details page, when the characters in the user name is around 27 or more, it is not aligned correctly.
The position of the "Awarded xxx" and user card is displayed below the question title.

This happened for many of the badges page. For example, in the [Good Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/good-question) badge you can see the user name are not aligned correctly.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: badges page]

**Configurations:**
Operating System: Windows 10
Google Chrome: Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Mozilla Firefox: 72.0.2 (64-bit)
Zoom: 100%

Comment: Time to insert a break in the usernames, and spread them over two rows. That would be less disruptive IMHO.

Comment: See also: [Inconsistent alignment in the badge history for people with long usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377045/inconsistent-alignment-in-the-badge-history-for-people-with-long-usernames) for more details.