# Inconsistent alignment in the badge history for people with long usernames

Tags: bug, design, badges, display-names

There seems to be an inconsistent alignment in the badge history for people with long usernames.
For example, in the badge history for the "[Necromancer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)" badge, Sonic and iBug's usernames have practically the same length:

[image]

Yet there's an alignment issue:

[image]

Note that the number of characters doesn't matter; ["mmm" is longer than "iii"](https://ibb.co/jfMDxSK) even though they have the same number of characters.

IMO, the usernames could be shifted to the left depending on how long the username is:

[image: Suggested improvement]

The questions can be broken down into multiple lines anyway, so IMO a left-shift shouldn't be a problem.

---

Though this may be a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342825/alignment-issue-in-the-individual-badge-details-page) from 2 years ago, I don't think the problem in the linked question is presented correctly. The OP assumes that the issue occurs for "around 27 *characters* or more" when this is not the case (see my comment below). It seems to be based on the length of the username (as seen visually/spatially) rather than the number of characters. For example, "ijokeijokeijokeireallydojoke" is 28 characters long, but it's still visually/spatially the same length as "iBug says Reinstate Monica" (which is 26 characters long), so "ijokeijokeijokeireallydojoke" would not cause an alignment issue even though it is 28 characters long.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist If it's a duplicate of a 2 year old question, it's about time they answer/fix it.

Comment: Funny. There's a username in the linked question which has 25 characters (GhostCat salutes Monica C) and does *not* fit. In the example in my question, there's a username that has 26 characters (iBug says Reinstate Monica) and still fits. [Note that they're practically the same length even with a one-character difference](https://ibb.co/RT0HRXL).