# Can we preserve the right alignment of usercards in the recently awarded lists of badges

Tags: feature-request, design, badges, help-center

I was browsing the [list of recently awarded Necromancer badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) and noticed that some of the usercards where aligned to the left, instead of to the right. It is obvious that these usercards don't fit in their entirety next to the space reserved for the post title (which clearly isn't always used), but there should be a cleaner solution then pushing them to the next line. The usercards get either too long because of a long username, labels next to the username, or just an insane number of badges; yes, I'm looking at you, [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9).

[image: Screenshot of the recently awarded necromancer badges, showing some usercards aligned to the left on the next line, whilst the majority of usercards are aligned right in the same line as the post title.]

I could see a few possible solutions:

- Make the space allocated for usercards a little wider, this could lead to extra whitespace between titles and usercards where there are long titles that need to wrap.
- Decouple the "Awarded X" from the usercard, so that they can stay on separate lines.
- Optimize the area used for the titles, if the entire length isn't needed, use less so the usercards can actually fit.
- Put the username under the title standard. This would mean the page length increases about 1 to 2 lines per question, but mostly one due to less need for wrapping post titles.

Comment: Also reported here: [Alignment issue in the individual badge details page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342825/alignment-issue-in-the-individual-badge-details-page). The 'Linked' questions list there turns up these: [Inconsistent alignment in the badge history for people with long usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377045) and [Long usernames skew "Others with this badge" list item alignment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349781).

Comment: @TheAmplitwist knew I had seen this before.

Comment: Thanks for finding that @TheAmplitwist. Back in my mind I knew I'd seen it teported before but couldn't find it.